# Cannot get data from Elastic 6.0: “error”:”Content-Type header [text/plain] is not supported”,”status”:406

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I create a client in java and want to get the query results from index but got the 406 error:
"Content-Type header [text/plain] is not supported","status":406.

Java platform: 1.6

ES version: 6.0

Below is the code snippet:

```
  Client clientInstance = Client.create();
  clientInstance.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("", ""));
 WebResource webResource =
  clientInstance.resource("http://hostname:9200/indexname/_search");
ClientResponse response=webResource.entity(dsl).accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class); 
String result = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

I use the dsl in Kibana and can get the correct query results. But it did not get the correct response in java and throw 406 error.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply need to add another `Content-type` HTTP request header for the `application/json` mime type since you're sending some JSON and ES doesn't guess your content type anymore:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource
    .entity(dsl)
    .header("Content-type", "application/json")       <--- add this 
    .accept("application/json")
    .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, it the fixes the issue perfectly.

Comment: where do you make this modification?

Comment: @dunPushedthatPanicButton not sure what you're asking

Comment: If anyone is using jmeter and encounter same error then add "HTTP Header Manager" and add "Name: Content-type   Valueapplication/json" and then run test