# Elasticsearch: Content-Type header is missing

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am ingesting data in AWS Elasticsearch (v 6.3) using python 2.7 and while adding data(json) I am getting

```
response: {"error":"Content-Type header is missing","status":406}...message: {"error":"Content-Type header is missing","status":406}
```

I have installed latest elasticsearch lib with `pip install elasticsearch`.

I am ingesting the json files of AWS Config snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with ES 6.0 [Content-Type header is obligatory](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests). If you are using [this script](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-to-elasticsearch) then the aforementioned `elasticsearch` python library changes nothing since this script does not use this library.

As a workaround, you could use AWS Elasticsearch 5.6 (should work until you figure out how to send Content-Type header). If you can edit the script, consider setting headers manually (good example can be found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364350/cannot-get-data-from-elastic-6-0-error-content-type-header-text-plain-is-n/48364371#48364371).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I am using that script. Thanks for the suggestions, will try them tomorrow.